# File error: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, multi-web-mode

Tags: config

I want to load the `multi-web-mode` package and have put it in `~/.emacs.d/` or `~/` or `~/.emacs.d/lisp/`(so far).

My `.emacs` contains the standard from the multi-web-mode distribution:

```
(require 'multi-web-mode)
(setq mweb-default-major-mode 'html-mode)
(setq mweb-tags 
  '((php-mode "<\\?php\\|<\\? \\|<\\?=" "\\?>")
    (js-mode  "<script[^>]*>" "</script>")
    (css-mode "<style[^>]*>" "</style>")))
(setq mweb-filename-extensions '("php" "htm" "html" "ctp" "phtml" "php4" "php5"))
(multi-web-global-mode 1)
```

I get:

```
File error: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, multi-web-mode
```

I was expecting that emacs would search in some of my directories and automatically discover it.

When I add

```
(load-file "~/.emacs.d/lisp/multi-web-mode.el")
```

or

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/")
```

to the `.emacs` file the emacs lisp file is loaded alright.

Is there really no user directory where the .el files are automatically loaded from? Would I always need to do `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/")` everytime I setup emacs?

Comment: What's wrong with adding that dir to `load-path`. If you expect to load libraries from that dir then you need to tell that to Emacs, one way or another. Just do that in your init file. Or put the library in some dir that is already in your `load-path`. Directly or indirectly, you are the one who puts that library in that dir. Directly or indirectly, you are the one who needs to tell Emacs about that.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with adding `load-path`. I was just expecting that it would seek in some user directory. I don't do much lisp programming and tend to forget syntax and names.

Answer (score 6):

You can type `M-x ielm`

Then in the REPL type `load-path` to see what the default is.
I know package manager appends to it but I'm not sure what else (if anything) does. You can add `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/")` to your `init.el` file. It is good to get used to modifying your `init.el` file.
I actually have multiple *.el files for my configuration that I modify. The more you use emacs the more you will want to customize it to your needs. If you search the web for emacs configuration you will find many examples on github.

I setup my `.emacs.d` directory with a small 'init.el' that contains `load-path` adjustments and a few other small things. Then I have an `emacs-config` directory that contains more .el files including but not limited to:

```
.emacs.d/home/emacs-config:

  dired-setup.el
  emacs-config.el
  hydra-binding.el
  ibuffer-setup.el
  init.el
  key-binding.el
  org-setup.el
  util-functions.el
  window-setup.el
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple explanation for this issue is that in your init file, `require` appears before `package-initialize`.